# Karma is erroring with ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module on the karma config file itself

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

I've got the angular and angular-mocks files in the karma config file, but it is erroring before I even get there..

All of the documentation online on this reference error says I don't have angular-mocks installed, but I'm pretty sure that's an error on the module variable in the spec files, not the initial karma config.

Here's my config file.

```
module.exports = function ( karma ) {
```

karma.set({
    /** 
     * From where to look for files, starting with the location of this file.
     */
    basePath: '../',

```
/**
 * This is the list of file patterns to load into the browser during testing.
 */
files: [
  'vendor/angular/angular.js',
  'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'vendor/angular-bootstrap-jbruni/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
  'vendor/placeholders/angular-placeholders-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.min.js',
  'vendor/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
  'vendor/angular-breadcrumb/angular-breadcrumb.js',
  'vendor/restangular/dist/restangular.js',
  'build/templates-app.js',
  'build/templates-common.js',

  'src/**/*.js',
  'src/**/*.coffee',
],
exclude: [
  'src/assets/**/*.js'
],
frameworks: [ 'jasmine' ],
plugins: [ 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-firefox-launcher', 'karma-coffee-preprocessor' ],
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.coffee': 'coffee',
},

/**
 * How to report, by default.
 */
reporters: 'dots',

/**
 * On which port should the browser connect, on which port is the test runner
 * operating, and what is the URL path for the browser to use.
 */
port: 9018,
runnerPort: 9100,
urlRoot: '/',

/** 
 * Disable file watching by default.
 */
autoWatch: false,

/**
 * The list of browsers to launch to test on. This includes only "Firefox" by
 * default, but other browser names include:
 * Chrome, ChromeCanary, Firefox, Opera, Safari, PhantomJS
 *
 * Note that you can also use the executable name of the browser, like "chromium"
 * or "firefox", but that these vary based on your operating system.
 *
 * You may also leave this blank and manually navigate your browser to
 * http://localhost:9018/ when you're running tests. The window/tab can be left
 * open and the tests will automatically occur there during the build. This has
 * the aesthetic advantage of not launching a browser every time you save.
 */
browsers: [
  'Firefox'
]
```

});
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had similar issue.

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module`

After including the path to the 'angular-mocks.js' in the 'files:' section of the karma config file, it was able to find the module.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '../js/angular.min.js',
  '../js/myutils-service.js',
  './angular-mocks.js',
  './my-service.js'
],
```